# Learning Spring MVC For web-projects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have looked at Spring MVC a few times briefly, and got the basic ideas. However whenever I look closely it seems to require you already know a whole load of 'core Spring'. The book I have for instance has a few hundred pages before it gets onto Spring MVC... which seems a lot to wade through. I'm used to being able to jump in, but there's so much bean-related stuff and XML, it just looks like a mass of data to consume.

Does it simplify if you put the time in, or is Spring just a much bigger framework than I thought? is it possible to learn this side of it in isolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@John `Spring just a much bigger framework than I thought?` - probably so, at least I thought so.

`is it possible to learn this side of it in isolation?` - Yes , here is a good way to learn your way http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html

And also I'd recommend you read a book `manning spring in action 2nd edition`, I also was learning spring from zero, and now I'm comfortable with it after reading this book, of course you have to refer to reference every now and then.

Here is where you can get basic info about MVC concept if you are not already familiar with(its in php, but important thing is point not syntax)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/mvc-for-noobs/

**EDIT**

If you want to see MVC in action, with examples or other spring uses use this repository https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples to checkout some projects , you'll see mvc-basic, mvc-ajax ..etc this is really good resource , you can checkout projects with Tortoise SVN on windows or subeclipse from eclipse

Comment: I think that _is_ the book I bought actually,

Comment: @c0mrade so you find it bad? I find it excellent, its probably not meant to be read from cover to cover that's why I haven't but I read most of it and I liked it

Answer (score 1):

At least you need to understand the core Spring - dependency injection, application context configuration and so on. It's actually not too complex, just a bit hard to start. For an experienced developer it might make sense to take a look at some sample app for the basic setup.

ps. I've got this [sample project for JSF/Spring/JPA/Hibernate combination](http://confluence.highsource.org/x/JIBM). Not Spring-MVC, but may be still helpful.

Comment: @lexicore there is nothing here m8 and you need username & pass to access svn

Comment: Here's a direct link to the project: http://repository.highsource.org/maven2/releases/org/hisrc/hifaces20/hifaces20-demo-messageboard/0.1.0/hifaces20-demo-messageboard-0.1.0-project.zip

Answer (score 1):

I myself am trying to learn Spring MVC from NetBeans official documentation from here:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html

Coming from ASP.Net/C#, it feels like there are so many steps to do in that simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Spring is that you can pick and choose what you use. If you want to use Spring, you don't have to jump in head first, you can just try it out by, say, using the Dependency Injection features, or by using the JDBC Template stuff. My recommendation would be to start small, and see how you like it.

To use the Web MVC stuff, you will need to understand Dependency Injection for configuring your controllers. You can choose to use the older more flexible XML-style configuration, or you can use the newer Annotations. Or you can mix and match. Starting with XML would probably be best as it will help you understand how stuff is working (it'd be like learning C and C++ before Java). Then you can move to using Annotations. Personally, I use XML to instantiate all my beans. I use the @Autowire annotation to inject dependencies. This seems to be the sweet spot for most flexibility and ease of use.